# have loaded pags locally when retrieve new page data jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, scroll, lazy-loading

I use a simple jqgrid and I load data on demand when scroll to the bottom fires.
the point is i want to preserve the previous loaded data (loaded page) and load the new data on scroll(new page) i dont know how to preserve previous data when scroll to bottom happens old data is substituted with new one how can i solve it?

```
        $Grid.jqGrid({
        type:'POST',
        datatype:'jsonstring',
        datastr:data,
        // url:data,
        // datatype: 'json',
        jsonReader:{
            repeatitems:false,
            root:"result",
            total:function (obj) {
                return obj.total;
            },
            records:"total"
        },
        direction:"rtl",
        sortable:true,
        colNames:[Dictionary.Statement().serial , Dictionary.Statement().date, Dictionary.Statement().time, Dictionary.Statement().credit, Dictionary.Statement().debit, Dictionary.Statement().balance, Dictionary.Statement().details, Dictionary.Statement().description, '', '', '', '', ''],
        colModel:[
            { label:'serial', name:'serial', index:'serial', search:true, width:100, align:'center' },
            { label:'date', name:'date', index:'date', width:50, editable:true, jsonmap:"shamsiDate.date", align:'center' },
            { label:'time', name:'time', index:'time', width:50, editable:true, jsonmap:"shamsiDate.time", align:'center' },
            { label:'credit', name:'credit', index:'credit', width:150, align:'center', editable:true },
            { label:'debit', name:'debit', index:'debit', width:50, align:'right', editable:true },
            { label:'balance', name:'balance', width:50, search:true, align:"right", editable:true },
            { label:'details', name:'details', width:50, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false, align:"center", formatter:jqgridSetting.ShowRowDetailsCol },
            { label:'description', name:'description', index:'description', sortable:false, hidden:true, hidedlg:true },
            { label:'branchCode', name:'branchCode', hidden:true, hidedlg:true },
            { label:'branchName', name:'branchName', hidden:true, hidedlg:true },
            { label:'registrationNumber', name:'registrationNumber', hidden:true, hidedlg:true },
            { label:'agentBranchCode', name:'agentBranchCode', hidden:true, hidedlg:true },
            { label:'agentBranchName', name:'agentBranchName', hidden:true, hidedlg:true }
        ],
        rowNum:50,
        pager:'#StatementPager',
        sortname:'date',
        viewrecords:true,
        sortorder:"desc",
        caption:"صورت حساب",
        gridview:true,
        rownumbers:true,
        shrinkToFit:true,
        autowidth:true,
        loadComplete:function () {
            jqgridSetting.SetRowStyle();
        },
        subGrid:true,
        subGridRowExpanded:function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
            addRowData = $Grid.jqGrid('getRowData', row_id);
            var html = '<span style=" direction: rtl;float: right;margin-right:10px">' + addRowData.description + '</span>';
            $("#" + subgrid_id).append(html);
            jqgridSetting.EditSubgrid();
        },
        gridComplete:function () {
            var subGridHeader = $('.StatementGridWrapper').find('#StatementGrid_subgrid').children(':first');
            if ($('span.ui-icon-plus', '#jqgh_StatementGrid_subgrid').length == 0) {
                subGridHeader.append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>').css('margin', '-1px 2px 0px 0px');
                $(subGridHeader.children('span.ui-icon-plus')[0]).click(function () {
                    jqgridSetting.ShowMoreInfo()
                });
            }
            jqgridSetting.SetGridHeaderStyle('#StatementGrid_rn');

            $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv','#gview_StatementGrid').on('scroll', function (e) {
                var $o = $(e.currentTarget);
                if ($o[0].scrollHeight - $o.scrollTop() <= $o.outerHeight()) {
                    alert('scrolltobottom');
                    var totalRow = $Grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount');
                    var formData = {
                        'offset':totalRow == 0 ? 0 : totalRow - 1,
                        'length':50,
                        'depositNumber':$("#depositNumber").val(),
                        'action ':$("#action").val(),
                        'fromDate':$("#fromDate").val(),
                        'toDate':$("#toDate").val(),
                        'fromTime':$("#toTime").val(),
                        'toTime':$("#fromTime").val()
                    }
                    jqgridSetting.PostFormData("/statement/search", formData, 'Statement.SetupStatementGrid', true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $Grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#StatementPager', { edit:false, add:false, del:false, search:false });
```

Comment: It's unclear what kind on scrolling you mean. Do you mean problems in `$('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv','#gview_StatementGrid').on('scroll', ...)`  part of your code? Do you really use `datatype:'jsonstring', datastr:data` and not `datatype: 'json'`? Do you implemented paging on the server side? How many data can be maximal loaded in jqGrid (50, 1000, 10000 or more)? Probably `datatype: 'json'` with `loadonce: true` would be the best choice for you?

Comment: @Oleg thanks Oleg for ur reply, FIRST OF ALL yes iam using datatype:'jsonstring', datastr:data not datatype: 'json' because the server reply is json and i don't know why but when i use datatype: 'json' it doesn't work i mean the data doesn't get loaded so when i changed it to datatype:'jsonstring', datastr:data it works fine. if this has any problems would u plz tell me what is wrong?

Comment: SECOND OF ALL for clearing my question iam tring to use scroll instead of paging (like facebook for example) my issue is about the code inside $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv','#gview_StatementGrid').on('scroll',...) when i scroll to the end of the grid server gave me next 50 rows and i cant save the previous loaded rows is there any way to save the prev. rows locally         or something like that or any better solution on this?

Comment: and i have hundreds of rows is it a good solution to use loadonce ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see many small problems in your code. I would recommend you to use `datatype:'json'` together with `loadonce: true` instead of `datatype:'jsonstring'`. If you have hundreds of rows then the loading of all data is quick enough in my experience. So you can return from the server just *all rows*. jqGrid will display the first 50 rows (because you use `rowNum:50`) and the user can use *local* paging of data which is typically very quickly.

If you have problems in usage of `datatype:'json'` and loading of data directly then you should append your question with **exact** response from the server. I personally use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) to trace HTTP traffic between the client and the server. You will find the exact JSON data here. Typical error of beginners is additional manual converting of data (of object) to JSON string. In the case the JSON string will be converted to JSON *the second time* by .NET framework. In the case one see escaped quotes in the server response (`\"`). Probably you have another problem, but to localize it one need see the server response.

If you need post additional data to the server `depositNumber`, `action`, `fromDate`, `toDate` and so on you can use `postData` which properties are defined as functions (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935)) for more details.